# .NET ClickOnce Application forgets one user's settings (but works for everyone else)

Tags: .net, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce application that has worked fine for nearly 10 years. However, just recently one user has experienced something I've never seen before. When I deploy a new version, the next time she starts the program it suggests the upgrade, She downloads & runs the new version, and everything is fine. However, the next time she opens the app it forgets her user configuration and the program version number is set back to it's default value, although the program itself works fine. No-one else has this problem. She (like everyone else) is using Windows 10.

And because it no longer knows the version of the app she doesn't get the next ClickOnce update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this turned out to be a problem with "Pin to Taskbar". This user had pinned the application to the Taskbar. But when the ClickOnce application was upgraded the Pinned link to the application didn't work correctly anyone.
Solution: Don't pin a ClickOnce app to the Taskbar

Comment: Although I agree with this answer, I really wish there was at least an explanation for this. The settings seem to reset to default (after installing an update) when it runs from the pinned taskbar shortcut.

Comment: Yes, it's very annoying. I agree.

Comment: I'm guessing there just aren't a lot of people who use ClickOnce....